# I have lost my account in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, accounts

I have accidentally removed my email in `my logins`. Now i have just entered again same email I used to log in before but I found just 1 of my reputations. I have lost everything.

Here [my previous account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998158/echo-me) and it looks there I have reputations normal with my nick name.

How can I recover my account with my all reputations?

I have looked to ask one moderator but I guess its impossible here.

**To moderators :** I have same email here and the one I showed up. Please help me get my real account back.

Answer (score 10):

Use the ["contact us"](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and write to the team with all the details. They will investigate and resolve your issue.