# Logging in with a deleted Google account

Tags: discussion, support, accounts

On the 16th of this month, I got logged out of my other Stack Overflow account: 11691977.

The *problem*: I deleted the Google account about a month ago (now unrecoverable), which I was using to log in to this account.

At first, I thought it was my GitHub account I was using. But no it's definitely that deleted Google account.

Is there a way for me to get back to my account? I have ways to prove that the account belongs to me.

I also tried contacting at https://stackoverflow.com/contact, though I haven't gotten a response back yet.

Thank you all.

PS: I asked this question earlier, but it got duplicated with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277230/i-have-lost-my-account-in-stack-overflow), which is not exactly my situation.

---

Update ( 6th of May, 2021 )

I got that other account of mine merged into this one. Thank you Stack Overflow team.

Comment: There's nothing the community can do for you here... I'm afraid you'll just have to be patient and wait for a response from your contact form submission.

Comment: *"I also tried contacting at https://stackoverflow.com/contact, though haven't gotten a response back yet."* That seems to be the best course of action. There nothing the community can really do to help you here. Unless you can find a device you're still logged into the service on, and then you can add some other authentication method to that account.

Comment: If you lost any access to the previous account and its signup accounts, an alternative recourse is probably to get it merged with this account. However, only SE staff can merge accounts since they need conclusive evidence, mods can't even do it.

Comment: @Larnu I don't believe that a device "still logged in" may work. Authorization goes through Google, which has revoked any token previously associated with the account. This reminds the importance to have recovery email addresses. Any "still logged in device" will be bumped on the very first connection to Google servers, whether it is a browser pointed at https://www.google.com or an Android device rebooted for first time after years

Comment: Do you have any old session token cookies from before you were logged out of SO? While they won't work, they might serve as evidence of account ownership if SO tracks old tokens or if the tokens contain any kind of cryptographic proof (doubtful but some sites work that way). Try to preserve any data that could serve as evidence of ownership.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE unluckily no. I'd never imagined I'd be needing them. though I have other ways to prove like: I have access to the recovery mail for the deleted account. The github and twitter on the account's profile are mine and I'm currently logged into those right now.

Comment: @kenzotenma: Not even in backups or anything?

Comment: unless you deleted the previous question you asked, the only other question you asked previously isn't closed as a duplicate of anything.  Probably should close one of the 2 questions as dups of each other

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I don't follow, what kind of backup is it?

Comment: Do you know if you are possibly logged in on any other device or anything? Perhaps on any other web browser across several devices?

Comment: @Clockwork sadly no. I think the only option I have is to wait for the team to get in touch with me.